# Problemas al conectar custom RPC con discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy enfrentando problemas al intentar conectar pypresence con discord.py para mostrar un Rich Presence en Discord pero el codigo no va aqui dejo el evento que hace lo del estado de discord para ver si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo y asi hacer que funcione este evento haciendo que se vean los botones y el estado. Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    rpc = pypresence.Presence(
        state="Custom Status",
        details="Selfbot",
        large_image="https://example.com/image.png",
        small_image="assets text name",
        small_text="Game RPC",
        buttons=[
            {
                "label": "Join",
                "url": "https://discord.gg/your-server-invite"
            },
            {
                "label": "Donate",
                "url": "https://www.paypal.me/your-paypal-link"
            }
        ]
    )

    asyncio.create_task(rpc.connect())
    print('RPC has running...')
```

A pesar de dedicar una cantidad significativa de tiempo y esfuerzo a la revisión y mejora de mi script, sigo enfrentando obstáculos considerables. La frustración se intensifica al notar que el script no logra actualizar mi estado en Discord y, para complicar las cosas, se cierra de manera inesperada en distintos momentos. Este comportamiento impredecible ha agotado mis recursos de resolución de problemas, y ahora busco la asistencia de la comunidad para identificar y resolver los problemas fundamentales en el código.

La búsqueda de errores en el script no ha arrojado resultados concluyentes hasta ahora, lo que subraya la complejidad del desafío. Mi determinación para superar estos problemas persiste, y estoy ansioso por recibir cualquier orientación, sugerencia o corrección que puedan ofrecer los miembros de la comunidad. Valoraré profundamente cualquier conocimiento compartido que contribuya a estabilizar el script y mejorar su funcionalidad.

Estoy dispuesto a aprender de las experiencias y conocimientos de la comunidad para avanzar hacia una implementación exitosa en Discord. Agradezco de antemano su colaboración y aportes en este proceso, sabiendo que su ayuda será clave para superar estos desafíos técnicos. ¡Gracias por dedicar su tiempo y experiencia a esta causa!

Comment: porfavor diganme si se entiende lo que intento preguntar

Comment: Me agrada la actitud que tienes, ¿alguna documentación que podamos revisar? por otro lado, aprende a manejar la frustración mediante la formulación de preguntas debido a que: 1. La frustración aparece porque en teoría todo debe funcionar y en la práctica, errores en algún lado. 2. La frustración ataca a cualquier programador, depende del nivel de manejo emocional, puede o bien quemarte o bien alentarte a cambiar de ruta manteniendo el objetivo intacto. 3. Preguntar en masa genera un grupo de buenas preguntas, al querer responderlas, encuentras nuevos caminos. PD: Aprende a usar `logs`. Saludos

Comment: porque me denuncian siempre solo quiedo saber el problema

Comment: ¿Denunciar? Tu pregunta ni siquiera la he reportado por baja calidad. Masbien, antes de hacer drama innecesario, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Oh lo siento esque todos me lo cierran :(

Comment: Perdoname es la costumbre de cosas que me pasan en todas las webs además que soy nuevo

Comment: Así que lo siento mucho ya te dejo tranquilo

Comment: No te entiendo. Quieres ayuda, te doy ayuda (aunque parece que no lo ves así), sigues sin leer el recorrido. Si te cierran la pregunta es porque no encaja con la dinámica del sitio (que está descrito en el tour) y hay que mejorarla, te digo cómo con las sugerencias y ni caso. Buena suerte y éxitos con la aventura, alguien más te dará una mano de alguna u otra manera. Saludos.

Comment: Ya te entiendo gracias

Comment: Que quieres decir con documentacion